# Rails generated query result is empty, but returns value in Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql-9.1

I'm having a strange problem in Rails with a Postgres query.

The query looks something like this:

```
WeeklyPlanner.find_or_create_by_user_id(current_user.id).recipes.find(:all, 
:conditions => ["
    weekly_planner_events.time_start = 
    date_part('epoch', to_timestamp(?)::timestamptz at time zone 'CDT')",
    Time.local(Time.now.year, Time.now.month, Time.now.day).to_i  
])
```

This generates (as I can view in the console), the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" 
INNER JOIN "weekly_planner_events" ON "recipes"."id" = "weekly_planner_events"."recipe_id" 
WHERE "weekly_planner_events"."weekly_planner_id" = 2 
AND (weekly_planner_events.time_start = date_part('epoch', to_timestamp(1347426000)::timestamptz at time zone 'CDT'))
```

My problem is that the generated SQL statement works well on psql or pgAdmin, but on rails it returns an empty array. That is, if I copy and paste it as is on a postgres console, it works perfectly fine, but when I run it on the Rails console, it returns nothing, and I have no idea why its happening.

I've tried the following:

- Parametrizing 'epoch' and 'CDT'/timezone (in order to remove `'`s
- Switching to a `where` statement, with the same condition
- Passing the variables with `#{}`s

Doing the search *without* the `date_part('epoch', [float])` function works fine in Rails, but its obviously not the result I need.

I'm finding this issue quite confusing, if there is any other data you need please let me know and I will edit the post.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you are using the `find_or_create` method it is using the create action, so you create a new `WeeklyPlanner` for a user, and this brand new `WeeklyPlanner` doesn't have recipes attached to it because it has just been created.
When you go to `psql`, you probably use a existent `WeeklyPlanner`.
But this is just a guess.

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm pretty sure it fetches the existing WeeklyPlanner. Its always `find`ing, instead of creating, at least for this particular one.